# Possible to compare part of strings in if-condition?

Tags: regex, perl

The below script does what I want, but it seams *wrong* to have two extra lines of regex.

The length of the part before the first `/` can be any length, so I don't suppose I can use `substr()`...

**Question**

Would it be possible to avoid the two extra regex lines and do it in the if-condition?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $a = "tank5/a/b";
my $b = "pool/a/b";

$a = $1 if $a =~ qr{.+?/(.+)};
$b = $1 if $b =~ qr{.+?/(.+)};

if ($a eq $b) {
    print "same\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
print "same\n" if (last_part($a) eq last_part($b));
sub last_part { $_[0] =~ s{^.*?/}{/}r }
```

If you don't have 5.14+, you'd have to use something a little wordier.

```
sub last_part { my ($s) = @_; $s =~ s{^.*?/}{/}; $s }
```

Comment: Using non-greediness to prevent the previous atom from matching something is error-prone. I avoid this use. I'd use the clearer `s{^[^/]*/}{/}`

Comment: Btw m{.+?/(.+)} ? $1 : $_; is more close to original idea.

Comment: @Сухой27, It's always error prone to use non-greediness to prevent an expression from matching something because it doesn't inherently prevent the expression made non-greedy from matching anything. Maybe you meant "In which circumstances does it not prevent the match?" Here's one: `"a!b!c!" =~ /^(.*?)!(.*?)!\z/`

Comment: @ikegami tnx for clarification, but this is still DWIM to me due `\z` anchor (I would not expect non greediness in such case).

Comment: @Сухой27, Look again. The second `(.*?)!` matches `b!c!`, so the non-greediness didn't stop `!` from being matched.

Answer (score 0):

> The length of the part before the first / can be any length, so I
>   don't suppose I can use substr()...

You can:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;

my $a = "tank5/a/b";
my $b = "pool/a/b";

$a = substr $a, (index $a, '/');
say $a;
$b = substr $b, (index $b, '/');
say $b;

--output:--
/a/b
/a/b
```

With the match operator(m//):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;

my $a = "tank5/a/b";
my $b = "pool/a/b";

my $regex = qr{
    (
       \/   #Literal '/', followed by...
       .*   #Any charcter 0 or more times.
    )
}xms;


if ($a =~ $regex) {
    my $match_a = $1;

    if ($b =~ $regex ) {
        my $match_b = $1;
        say 'the same' if $match_a eq $match_b;
   }
}
```